# OpenGL with dual monitors

Tags: opengl, glut, multiple-monitors

I want to develop one OpenGL application that is using the two monitors for display. However, if I specify the window size in `glutInitWindowSize()` to be the size which is the sum of the two monitors, then the result window is still always in one monitor, even though I can drag the window to another monitor or reshape.

Does OpenGL automatically detect another monitor and use the total size of the two monitors?

Comment: OpenGL is talking to the GPU, are you shure its talking to all GPU's?
http://www.rchoetzlein.com/theory/2010/multi-monitor-rendering-in-opengl/

Comment: Try Equalizer Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not OpenGL that is limiting the size of the window, **it's GLUT**.

You have to figure out a way to change the way GLUT sets up and creates a window. On Windows, it seems you can [use win32 API to change these settings](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/374407-glut-fullscreen---two-monitors/) during runtime.

Comment: @YanLi: Then also your Window Manager might be the culprit that prevents a window from spanning two screens. You'd have to use XRandR and/or Xinerama window manager hint properties to tell the WM that the window should span two monitors. Again this is not an OpenGL issue but one of the framework used. And I'm sorry to break it to you, but GLUT can't do it (yet). So either hack FreeGLUT or make your own framework, or use something that can deal with multimonitor (Qt for example).

Comment: @datenwolf OK, seems I need to learn X window programming. Could you recommend any good books or web tutorial to learn that?